# Create and group new array from object and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, higher-order-functions

I have an item object and each key is ID of item characteristic (color, size or material). Their values are also ID's of the characteristic value (red, blue, etc.)
I want to group each characteristic with its values (like in resultArray). I tried to use reduce function but I can't get the desired result. Can you give me a hint what methods to use to get this result?

```
itemAttributes = { "11": [ 19,20 ], "12": [ 21, 22, 23], "13": [ 25, 26, 27 ]}

arr1 =[ 
  {title: "colors", "id": 11 }, 
  {title: "sizes", "id": 12 }, 
  {title: "materials", "id": 13 }
]

arr2=[ 
  {title: "red", "attribute": 11, id: 19 },
  {title: "blue", "attribute": 11, id: 20 }, 
  {title: "10x20", "attribute": 12, id: 21 }, 
  {title: "10x30", "attribute": 12, id: 22 },
  {title: "10x40", "attribute": 12, id: 23 },
  {title: "10x50", "attribute": 12, id: 24 },
  {title: "metals", "attribute": 13, id: 25 },
  {title: "polymers", "attribute": 13, id: 26 },
  {title: "ceramics", "attribute": 13, id: 27 },
]

resultArray = [
  {
    title: colors,
    items: [red, blue],
  },
  {
    title: sizes,
    items: [10x20, 10x30, 10x40],
  },
  {
    title: materials,
    items: [metals, polymers, ceramics],
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest I can come up was with a `map` combined with an inner `filter`+`map`.
Since it is a transformation of `arr1`, `map` can be used. Inside I'm filtering from `arr2` the needed items and then transforming the filtered items to return an array of just titles

```js
let itemAttributes = { "11": [ 19,20 ], "12": [ 21, 22, 23], "13": [ 25, 26, 27 ]}

let arr1 =[ 
  {title: "colors", "id": 11 }, 
  {title: "sizes", "id": 12 }, 
  {title: "materials", "id": 13 }
]

let arr2=[ 
  {title: "red", "attribute": 11, id: 19 },
  {title: "blue", "attribute": 11, id: 20 }, 
  {title: "10x20", "attribute": 12, id: 21 }, 
  {title: "10x30", "attribute": 12, id: 22 },
  {title: "10x40", "attribute": 12, id: 23 },
  {title: "10x50", "attribute": 12, id: 24 },
  {title: "metals", "attribute": 13, id: 25 },
  {title: "polymers", "attribute": 13, id: 26 },
  {title: "ceramics", "attribute": 13, id: 27 },
]

const res = arr1.map(({title,id}) => {
  const attrIds = itemAttributes[id]
  const items = arr2.filter(({id}) => attrIds.includes(id)).map(({title}) => title)
  return {title,items}
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let itemAttributes = { "11": [ 19,20 ], "12": [ 21, 22, 23], "13": [ 25, 26, 27 ]}

let arr1 =[
    {title: "colors", "id": 11 },
    {title: "sizes", "id": 12 },
    {title: "materials", "id": 13 }
]

let arr2=[
    {title: "red", "attribute": 11, id: 19 },
    {title: "blue", "attribute": 11, id: 20 },
    {title: "10x20", "attribute": 12, id: 21 },
    {title: "10x30", "attribute": 12, id: 22 },
    {title: "10x40", "attribute": 12, id: 23 },
    {title: "10x50", "attribute": 12, id: 24 },
    {title: "metals", "attribute": 13, id: 25 },
    {title: "polymers", "attribute": 13, id: 26 },
    {title: "ceramics", "attribute": 13, id: 27 },
]

let resultArray = [];
arr1.map((atr) => {
    let filters = itemAttributes[atr.id];
    let toPush = {
        title: atr.title,
        items: []
    };
    arr2.map((item) => {
        if(item.attribute === atr.id && filters.includes(item.id))
            toPush.items.push(item.title)
    });
    resultArray.push(toPush);
})
console.log(resultArray)
```